# Sharing contact throught SMS

Tags: sms

When I am share the contact throught SMS, during the addition of contact it is converting to MMS formate and message is not going.
Please help me.
Phone mode: MIA3 andriod one

Answer (score 0):

> it is converting to MMS formate and message is not going

This only happens if you try to send the contact as a vcard file (.vcf is the extension).
To send the contact number only, copy the number to clipboard and paste it in message body. The message will be transferred as text.
If you want to send the message as a  vcard file, contact your cellular company (eg. Airtel , Jio, Vodafone etc) and request them to enable MMS on your number.